# How to get next all element of a specific class?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am triggering an event and the element has the class `.pvtd`. I have more elements with the same class name after that so I want to perform some functionality on all those elements which have the same class name after that element.

On selecting any option which is has no value I want the next `.pvtd` get disabled. The previous `.pvtd` class before the selected element should not be disabled, only the next ones. Any idea how I can do this?

```js
$('.pvtd').on('change', function(event) {
  let value = $(`${this} option:selected`).val();
  if (!value) {
    $('.pvtd').nextAll().attr("disabled", "disabled");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
  <label for="inputCity"><strong>Produce</strong></label>
  <select name="first" id="produce_rprt" class="pvtd">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select Produce</option>
    <option value="1">Potato</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-2">
  <label for="inputState"><strong>Variety</strong></label>
  <select name="variety" id="variety_rprt" class="pvtd">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select Variety</option>
    <option value="1">Default</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-2">
  <label for="inputState"><strong>Type</strong></label>
  <select name="type" id="type_rprt" class="pvtd">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select Type</option>
    <option value="1">Default</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-2">
  <label for="inputState"><strong>Defect</strong></label>
  <select name="defect" id="defect_rprt" class="pvtd">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select Defect</option>
    <option value="1">Default</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's two issues here. Firstly, `this` is a reference to the element which raised the event. As such you cannot concatenate it to a jQuery selector string. Aside from this you don't need to, as the value of the selected option can be read simply by doing `$(this).val()`.

Secondly, `nextAll()` won't work in this situation as the `.pvtd` are not siblings. To fix this you could select all of them, then when required, you can find all those elements with a higher index that the current one.

However, given your below comment:

> I want only type and defect to get disabled if I am selecting 'Select Variety'.

You do not need `nextAll()` in this case, as you only want the *single* following `.pvtd` element. To achieve that you can use `eq()`, like this:

```js
var $pvtd = $('.pvtd').on('change', function(event) {
  let value = $(this).val();
  if (!value) {
    $('.pvtd').eq($(this).index('.pvtd') + 1).prop("disabled", true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
  <label for="inputCity"><strong>Produce</strong></label>
  <select name="first" id="produce_rprt" class="pvtd">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select Produce</option>
    <option value="1">Potato</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
  <label for="inputState"><strong>Variety</strong></label>
  <select name="variety" id="variety_rprt" class="pvtd">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select Variety</option>
    <option value="1">Default</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
  <label for="inputState"><strong>Type</strong></label>
  <select name="type" id="type_rprt" class="pvtd">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select Type</option>
    <option value="1">Default</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
  <label for="inputState"><strong>Defect</strong></label>
  <select name="defect" id="defect_rprt" class="pvtd">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select Defect</option>
    <option value="1">Default</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: here if I am selecting  'Select Variety' then along with variety, type and defect are also getting disabled. I want only type and defect to get disabled if I am selecting 'Select Variety'.

Comment: In that case you don't need `nextAll()` at all. You can use `eq()` to get the next single `.pvtd` instance. I've edited the answer for you

Comment: Apart from the selected .pvtd instance,how to get all the next .pvtd instance?

Comment: That's what my original answer did: `$('.pvtd').slice($(this).index('.pvtd')).prop("disabled", true);`

Comment: your original answer is disabling the selected .pvtd instance as well.

Comment: Well yes, then just remove the `.prop()` call

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194034/discussion-between-sweta-sharma-and-rory-mccrossan).